# return a response diferrent in the deleteById, spring

Tags: java, spring

I'm a newbie in spring boot and I'm creating the method deleteById and I want check that user exist before.

How can i do to return a diferent message if the user exist or not?

Controller

```
@GetMapping(value = "/delete/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Personaje> deleteCharacter(@PathVariable("id") long id){
        Personaje p = this.characterService.deteleCharacter(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<Personaje>(p, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Service

```
public Character deteleCharacter(long id) { 
        Character ch = this.repository.findById(id);
```

for example, if the id no exits, return a message "the id not found"

Comment: Note: `Character` is the name of a core class in `java.lang`, and it is dangerous to reuse those names.

Comment: yes, I already change

Answer (score 0):

In the response entity, you can have something like this:

`return new ResponseEntity<>("The ID is not found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)`
As for the return statement, you can leave it as a generic so from `ResponseEntity<Personaje>` you instead do it `ResponseEntity<>`.

This way you can return a generic response entity, and then populate it with data if needed.